# Web Page Format Different on Smaller monitor using IE6

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, css

I have developed an ASP.NET web page using a widescreen monitor and IE10 as the browser. I opened the same exact page on a regular(not widescreen) monitor that was running IE6 and it looked all jacked up. It still functioned perfect but some of the transparency was gone and menus were all out of whack. Would this be the monitor or IE6? Just curious if any of you might of run into the same issue. I'm assuming it is the IE6 giving the issues because im using CSS3 in my web page. Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: Monitor? Probably not. IE6? Probably yes. CSS 2.1 + IE6? Partial. CSS 3 + IE6? Even less. Don't even try to hope that IE6 will be compatible with a page you designed and tested using IE 10. Really. It's sin even to think something like that. BTW don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), sometimes.

Comment: If you don't absolutely have to support Internet Explorer 6 for this project, then don't. It has terrible support even for relatively long lived CSS 2.1 layout properties, and almost none for anything introduced in CSS3 (the only properties supported will be those standardised from Internet Explorer and already existed then). If you are using HTML5 semantic elements you will need to tell Internet Explorer 8 and below about them and declare block styles before you can use them in layout, see https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE6 doesn't support most of the standards around displaying webpages (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) which have been around since decades.

Depending on the complexity of your project, it's unlikely that you will get the website to render properly on IE6 without substantial effort.

There are some hacks which can emulate a more standard conformant behavior on legacy browsers, like http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/ though.